# Good portal / app / technique to reduce ambient sound

Tags: sound-effects, voice, sound-effects-recording, voice-manipulation, cleaning

I have an audio that I would like to reduce ambient noise, it is an interview recorded with a mobile, just recording, and even I get to hear voices, I can not understand at all. The recording for the university did not go well, and even we tried before, that interview result in a very noisy file.

We can not repeat the 2 hours long interview.  :-((

I have tried with Audacity, and few “free” online tools, basically no one made anything usable,

The sound is mainly noise, I know, and probably I am asking for something only seen in movies and not real.

**May somebody give me a hint of the best posible result?**

- With https://audiodenoise.com/ I can get to hear some half words, but it is not enough
- With https://www.lalal.ai/voice-cleaner/ nothing at all
- https://noisereducer.media.io/denoise make a bit of work, but far from enough
- podcastle.ai/editor just silence all clip as trying to clean

I have uploaded a 1-minute demo to test it, previous results are based on that clip
https://www.whyp.it/tracks/68283/untitled-interview?token=isF9h

**if somebody could help us, It may save us the semester**

Comment: FYI, that's one of the worst I've ever heard lol. Congrats ;) I assume it's a mono recording?

Comment: I just tried Adobe's new podcast enhancer - see https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/52023/9601 & it rescued *something*, maybe enough to transcribe if not to use as audio.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to test if the audio was set to be downloadable rather than having to use Audio Hijack to grab it…
but I think yours is a lost cause.

On first listen I wasn't for quite sometime aware that there was supposed to be dialog in there. I kept waiting for it to start ;)

Izotope RX [about the best in the business] can remove all the noise… but what's left isn't usable. I'm assuming it's not in English which means I can't tell if the words are comprehensible enough to transcribe, but there's certainly not enough left to be considered a dialog track.

In future, even if you can't afford a dedicated sound engineer/boom op, at least do a sound check - record a couple of minutes as you're getting set up & test it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Spectralayers. It has a specific mode for extracting v voice from noise.

Answer (score -1):

With Adobe enhance you can have an AI tool that removes background noises and makes it sound as if the voice was recorded in a studio
https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance